# Two entities trouble

Tags: mysql, data-modeling

I have two entities that link to worm a link table, the primary key from both tables is referenced in the new table, services and members, forms Member_Services. In the services table I have a column named services requested, along with the Services id, these services are requested by members.

The thing is, I entered data into both parent tables, but I have a problem with the data for the link table. Some members requested more than one service, and I'm unable to enter their Member id more than once. can someone assist tell me how to change my table to accept the member detail a second time with a different requested service...

```
Create Table Member_Services
(
Services_ID integer(10) not null,
Member_ID integer(10) not null,
Primary Key (Services_ID),
Unique Key (Member_ID),
Foreign Key (Services_ID)
References Services(Services_ID),
Foreign Key (Member_ID)
References Member(Member_ID));
```

this is the code for the table

can someone assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the declaration of the keys.  You have two single column keys, which only allows one instance of a given Service and one instance of a given member.  What you need is a composite primary  key, to enforce uniqueness of the *combination* of a Member and a Service, but allow multiple occurrences of each.

```
Create Table Member_Services
(
    Services_ID integer(10) not null,
    Member_ID integer(10) not null,
    Primary Key (Services_ID, Member_ID),
    Foreign Key (Services_ID)
        References Services(Services_ID),
    Foreign Key (Member_ID)
        References Member(Member_ID)
);
```

This will permit one Member to have multiple Services, and also more than one Member to use the same Service.